# Extract multiple images from white context in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics

I have some scanned papers each with multiple rectangular pictures printed in a white context.
What I need to do is to detect the position of each picture inside the image and I need to do this in C#.
I have already checked some image processing libraries they all seemed to be for jobs far more complicated that this. This is no face detection etc.

Comment: So, sit down and reseach - that is a icmplex project. Or do you ask us to point you to some library? Off topic. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: In the lower level it will be something like pixel-by-pixel scan for non-white area, there is no secret, do you need a sample?

Comment: I need a hint to an approach more effective than starting form some corner and reading each pixel to the end. I was thinking as those pictures are not to be processed (just detected as rectangles) there must be some faster ways that does not require a thorough scan.

Comment: To detect an image in an rectangle format you must start with a pixel-by-pixel scan.

Comment: As there are white pixels in the vast majority, will this be a bad idea to pick some random pixels from difference positions and once a non-white one is found starting scan from the boundaries in that particular area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things like that I'm used to use ImageMagik

look at this: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=22475